# Angular2 onresize event inside div missing reference

Tags: angular, reference, onresize

currently i`m trying to find out how to handle window:onresize event in angular2.
i have embedded it in a components template like this:

```
<div class="signaturepadContainer" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
```

and handle the event in ts-file like

```
  onResize(event: any){ ...dosomethingterrible... }
```

in my 'event'-parameter i have in 'curenTarge', 'source' and 'target' reference to 'window', but not to my div.

Where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

By adding `window:` you make it a global event handler. Even though you added it to a div, it's not related to this div at all. It would behave the same no matter where you add it.

You can also use

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event: any){ ...dosomethingterrible... }
```

to have less confusing code.